# OS X Cmd+G starts searching for same text in different programs

Tags: macos, bug

I've noticed the following behavior, but cannot find a reason or a bug report on why this may be happening. Maybe this is normal on OSX?

The situation:

With the terminal open, I search for some text, say "hello", which exists in the terminal. I get a few matches and `Cmd+G` even searches for more occurrences.

I then switch to Chrome which has some web page open, and search for some text, say "world".

Here is the kicker: when I switch back to the terminal and press `Cmd+G`, the terminal is now searching for "world" instead of the original "hello" I searched for in ther Terminal.

Is there some option to fix this or is this a bug/designed behavior in OSX?

Version: OS X Yosemite 10.10.4

Comment: Personally, I had seen this as a feature, being able to carry the same search terms across several applications has been useful to me in the past.

Comment: I feel it is a bad choice (for programming users)

Answer (score 2):

It's a 'feature' - though its use in a Find dialog may have been almost accidental initially, it is actually an intentional usage.

OS X, in common with several other flavours of unix, has two copy buffers.

The one you know & love, cut/copy/paste itself on  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>X</kbd> ,  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>C</kbd>  &  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>V</kbd> 
& another, known as Kill & Yank, which can be called from  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>K</kbd>  &  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>Y</kbd> 
<sub>*though incidentally in Stack Exchange's markdown language,  <kbd>Ctrl ⌃</kbd>   <kbd>K</kbd>  will format as `code` instead.*</sub>  
Kill is the equivalent of Cut, rather than Copy, but Yank is equivalent to Paste.

It is actually this kill/yank buffer that most Find/replace dialogs use.
There is no way to avoid that, I'm afraid.